# Sudo command no longer functions properly

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

When I use the sudo command I get an error message.

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

If I try to use chmod on sudoers I get the message "Operation not permitted". Can someone help me fix things so sudo works again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get round this by rebooting into single user mode...

1. Reboot the computer holding <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
2. The command line should come up showing something about how to mount the drive in write mode `mount -uw /`, follow these steps.
3. Now you should be a root user able to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.
4. Issue `reboot now` to exit and reboot into normal mode.

*I don't have a second Mac to test these instructions are step-by-step complete and obviously can't write on the machine while it's rebooting, so please let me know if you get stuck on any steps.*

Comment: Just tested this, it should work, you might get asked to authenticate if you have FileVault enabled.

Comment: Yep it worked. I didn't see anything about mounting my drive but the command you gave me, mount -uw / appearantly worked fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to etresoft's suggestion of using *Get Info*

1> Finder -> Go -> Go to Folder: /etc

2> Select sudoers

3> Finder -> File -> Get Info

4> In the *Sharing & Permissions* secion, click & unlock the Padlock 
Set the permissions to:

---

system - Read only

wheel - Read only

everyone - No Access

Comment: Who is  etresoft ? There is no context to the name.